# Why my Python print command not working after "if" function?

Tags: python

Why my code doesn't write "good job"? It only jumps after "inp_user" and "inp_pin" to "question" imput.

...and loog not working too :D

```
username = "boy"
pin = 123
inp_user = input("User: ")
inp_pin = int(input("Pin: "))

def loop():
    if inp_user == username and inp_pin == pin:
        print("Good Job")
    else:
        print("Bruh")

question = input("again?: ")

def second():
    if question == "Yes":
        loop()
    else:
        exit
```

Comment: Where are you calling your functions? You don't call `second()`, so `loop()` never gets called either. Also, I don't think you have the right understanding of how functions work. All your variables are global anyway. You seem to have put some sections of code into "functions" and not called them. Try removing your functions completely, and get the code to work first, and then start thinking about functions. Also, at the moment, the way the code is written smells of a [spaghetti-style/goto approach](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Spaghetti_code), especially the way you've called `loop()`.

Comment: To be clear, the way you are writing the code appears like you are attempting to use the `loop` function essentially as a *label for a goto*, rather than as an actual function. If you want a loop, then you need to write one out (using `for` or `while`), or perhaps try a recursive approach instead.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

your code won't work because you don't call the cunctions you have defined

Try This:

```
username = "boy"
pin = 123

    
while True:

    inp_user = input("User: ").strip()
    inp_pin = int(input("Pin: ").strip())

    if inp_user == username and inp_pin == pin:
        print("Good Job")
    else:
        print("Bruh")
        question = input("again?: ")
        if question.strip() != "Yes":
            break
```

Answer (score 2):

You put the check code in functions, but you're never actually invoking those functions. So you've defined two functions, and that's it. The interpreter never actually steps through the `inp_user` and `inp_pin` checks.

And calling a function `loop` doesn't actually do anything if you don't… loop.

Finally `exit` is a function, just using it won't do anything.

Comment: Finally: `exit` is just the **name** of a function, not an actual function call, like `exit()` would be. (`exit()` would be, assuming that it's defined somewhere, e.g. `from sys import exit`. But it's still bad practice to call `sys.exit()` from a function, rather than just `return` from the function)

Answer (score 0):

It's good way to design your code according your task.

It seems your desire is to make **form** that takes a **two arguments**, and if it's correct, **it writes something**. Otherwise, user gets another try and returns to first step.

So first step is finding place for our ,let's say, static variables, correct variables. I think the better way in such simple task is passing this variables into function.

```
username = "boy"
pin = 123

def loop(): # <-- no argumets, which leads to useless function. Where should it take inputed data?
    if inp_user == username and inp_pin == pin:
        print("Good Job")
    else:
        print("Bruh")
```

Let's correct this:

```
inp_user = input("User: ") # <- Now it asks user to give a data
inp_pin = int(input("Pin: "))

def loop(inp_user, inp_pin): # <-Now it has arguments
    username = "boy"
    pin = 123     

    if inp_user == username and inp_pin == pin:
        print("Good Job")
    else:
        print("Bruh")

loop(inp_user, inp_pin) # <- NOTE THAT FUNCTION MUST BE CALLED
```

The next part is to create something that **gives another attempt**, otherwise **it's failed**. And your question must be something like: How I can terminate execution? It leads you to sys library, specifically to `sys.exit()`. Now you have everything you need to build this.

```
def second(): <- NO ARGS
    if question == "Yes": # <- WHAT IS THE QUESTION?
        loop() # <- What should I do???
    else:
        exit # <- WHO I AM?
```

Note that in python function can take varibles from outer space only via argumnets in function.

It's a good practice to build all bricks and then build a programm. So we need another function, that gives a second try if answer is YES.

```
def second(question_data):
    if question_data == "YES":
       return True
    else:
       return None
```

And entire code:

```
import sys

def second(question_data):
    if question_data == "YES":
       return True
    else:
       return None

def loop(inp_user, inp_pin): # <-Now it has arguments
    username = "boy"
    pin = 123     

    if inp_user == username and inp_pin == pin:
        print("Good Job")
    else:
        print("Bruh") 
        question = input("again?: ")
        future = second(question)
        if future:
           inp_user = input("User: ")
           inp_pin = int(input("Pin: "))
           loop(inp_user, inp_pin )
        else:
           sys.exit()

 inp_user = input("User: ")
 inp_pin = int(input("Pin: "))

 loop(inp_user, inp_pin)
```